# Two "Audio codecs" have 100% power usage in PowerTOP - what does this mean?

Tags: audio, power-management, intel, powertop

Should I be worried? 
My battery power doesn't last long (~1hr), could this be the reason? 
How can I fix this (if it has to be fixed at all)?

[image]

Comment: On the second line of your description, says "My doesn't last long" ... What do you mean?

Comment: Edited, I meant that my battery lasts a very short time (<1hr), and that it used to last longer (multiple hours). It could be either that it's permanently damaged, or that it's being drained by something - possibly this (actually this sounds kind of impossible, but that's why it's just a speculation).

Comment: you can manually fix it from powertop or create systemd service to do that for you on boot. If you need help with later method, let me know...

Answer (score 3):

A single session fix that I found is as follows. Go to the Tunables tab. There, one of the options will be : `Enable Audio codec power management` with the value `Bad`. Press Enter to change it to `Good`, and watch as your power consumption drops to a more bearable level

But this fix has to be done every time you reboot. I wish there were a way to make this permanent.